# (Dynamic layout) Button listener in my view update multiple textview instead of 1

Tags: java, android

I'm trying android for 2 weeks and I run into some problem.
I have a list of burger that I fetch from my database, I made a view with that.
The app needs to increment and decrement the quantity that the user wants so that he can pass an order.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMLn8.png)
My problem is that when I click on the + button, the app update multiple text view and I don't understand where that came from and how to fix it.

here is a sample of my code for the view :

```
package com.example.fastfood;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BurgerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Burger> {
    public BurgerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Burger> burgers) {
        super(context, 0,burgers);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        final Burger burger = getItem(position);
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_burger, parent, false);
        }
        TextView burgerName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.burgerName);
        TextView burgerPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.burgerPrice);
        TextView qteCmd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qteCmd);
        Button btnMoins = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.moins);
        Button btnPlus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
        btnMoins.setTag(qteCmd);
        btnPlus.setTag(qteCmd);
        btnMoins.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView qteCmd = (TextView) v.getTag();
                burger.changeQuantitee(-1);
                Log.d("DEBUG", "Button moins : "+burger.getNom()+" "+burger.getQuantitee()+" "+qteCmd.getId());
                qteCmd.setText(Integer.toString(burger.getQuantitee()));
            }
        });

        btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView qteCmd = (TextView) v.getTag();
                burger.changeQuantitee(1);
                Log.d("DEBUG", "Button moins : "+burger.getNom()+" "+burger.getQuantitee()+" "+qteCmd.getId());
                qteCmd.setText(Integer.toString(burger.getQuantitee()));
            }
        });
        burgerName.setText(burger.getNom());
        burgerPrice.setText(burger.getPrix()+"€");
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to alter views of an AdapterView (ListView, Spinner, RecyclerView etc) inside methods that do not belong to Adapter classes (as you do with your **onClick()** method overrides. What you should be doing is after you mutate your data model notify the Adapter with .**notifyDataSetChanged()**.

Also I strongly suggest that you do not capture the local variable **Burger** inside the **onClick()**. Rather, fetch the data from burgersList with adapter position. So your code be like:

```
 btnMoins.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView qteCmd = (TextView) v.getTag();
                Burger b = getItem(position);
                b.changeQuantitee(-1);
                Log.d("DEBUG", "Button moins : "+burger.getNom()+" "+burger.getQuantitee()+" "+qteCmd.getId());

               //Instead of changing the state of the TextView yourself, you should instead do following:
                BurgerAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```